# Get string source of Python xml ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

How would you get the source of an `ElementTree` as a string in Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(source)
root = tree.getroot()
ET.tostring(root)
```

Note that there may be formatting differences between the content of `source` and `ET.tostring(doc)`.

Comment: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tostring' happens when I tried this

Comment: @James: then you are calling it on the wrong object. It's the *module* that has that method.

Comment: @James: You are right that `ET.tostring(tree)` does not work if `tree` is an `ElementTree` (my mistake). Instead, get the root of the tree with `root = tree.getroot()`, and then call `ET.tostring(root)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes! Thank you for pointing that out. I will accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not, but I wonder why it wouldn't be:

```
tree.tostring(root)
```

instead of the current way:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(root)
```